# how to group an array based on a key inside a list using lodash in javascript

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

```
var data = { "offers" :[{id:1}, {id:2}],"products":[{"name":"nike","id":1},{"name":"puma","id":2},{"name":"nike","id":1}]};
```

how do I group my data to a new array so that the data can be dynamically fed to the modal and it gives me the expected output.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **_.values(object)** function of lodash to do so:

It creates an array of the own enumerable string keyed property values of the object.

*Note: Non-object values are coerced to objects.*

In your Ex.

```
var data = { "offers" :[{id:1}, {id:2}],"products":[{"name":"nike","id":1},{"name":"puma","id":2},{"name":"nike","id":1}]};

var arr = _.values(data);
```

hopefully, this will works for you!. thanks